# Вывод индексов по повторяющемуся имени

Tags: python, python-3.6

Есть скрипт:

```
list = []
input_name = 5
for i in range(input_name):
    list.append(input('Введите {0} имя: '.format(str(i+1))))

for i in range(len(list)):
    print('{0}'.format(str(list[i])), end='')
    if i != (len(list) - 1):
        print('.', end='')

x = list.index('Влад')
print('\n{0} позиция имени'.format(x + 1))
```

В котором пользователь заполняет лист именами и если в списке встречается имя "Влад" то выводится индекс этого имени.
Нужна помощь в том что если в лист записывается имя "Влад" например 2 раза нужно чтобы вывелся индексы этого имени.

Comment: Что бы вывелось "Влад" два раза с индексами? При условии если в списке будет два имя "Влад", так понял?

Comment: @ДанилкинPUBG - да, если пользователь в лист записывает 2 раза имя Влад то нужно чтобы вывелись индексы этого имени например (2, 4)

Answer (score 2):

```
INPUT_NAMES = 5

names = [input(f'Введите {i+1} имя: ') for i in range(INPUT_NAMES)]
indices = [i for i, name in enumerate(names) if name == 'Влад']

if indices:
    print(f'Имя Влад находится на позициях: {", ".join(map(str, indices))}.')
else:
    print('Нет имени Влад.')
```

---

*Примеры вывода этой программы

(для разных вводов):*

1. > ```
   > Имя Влад находится на позициях: 0, 1, 4.
   > ```
2. > ```
   > Имя Влад находится на позициях: 3.
   > ```
3. > ```
   > Нет имени Влад.
   > ```

---

Что я сделал в отличие от вас:

1. Имя константы написал *прописными буквами* в соответствии с [PEP-8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id29).
2. *Не использовал* имя `list` для списка, потому что *это имя стандартной функции*.
3. Вместо циклов использовал [генераторы списка](https://all-python.ru/osnovy/generator-spiska.html).
4. Вместо метода `.format()` применил [f-строки](https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings).
5. Использовал стандартную функцию [`enumerate()`](https://younglinux.info/python/feature/enumerate).
6. Сделал строку из отысканных индексов, чтобы они были на выводе отделены  запятой и пробелом: `", ".join(map(str, indices))`:

   - `map(str, indices)` применит функцию `str()` к всякому элементу списка `indices`,
   - затем `", ".join()` сделает из этого списка (уже строк) одну строку (с `", "` между индивидуальными элементами списка).

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ подсчёта дублируемых элементов в списке с индексом.

```
list = []
counter = []
input_name = 5
name = 'Влад'

for i in range(input_name):
    list.append(input('Введите {0} имя: '.format(str(i + 1))))

for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] == name:
        counter.append(i)

print(f'{name} под индексом: ', *counter)
```

Comment: а как это можно написать по стелистики моего кода чтобы это было не во дну строку?

Comment: если правильно понял, то чуть изменил код.

Answer (score 0):

```py
name_tofind = 'Влад'
name_count = 5
name_list = list()

for i in range(name_count):
    name_list.append( input(f'Введите {i+1} имя: ') )

indices = [i+1 for i, name in enumerate(name_list) if name == name_tofind]

print(f'{name_tofind} под индексом: ', *indices)
```